# Why does a function that's almost a copy of another fail to update output field?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working on making a PO form that will eventually submit the values to a database. When you look at the code, if you load it, you'll see the line items area. Quantity, Description, Loaction/Use and line total. Everything works great on the first line item, but when filling out the second line item, and the subsequent ones, the line total column doesn't calculate or show any values. The line total field is simple math; quantity * unit price = line total.
Again, the first rown works great. The second row and the others, well, nothing shows up in the line total field to the right and I can't figure out why. The calculations and functions called are all the same, the field IDs are all unique, I'm not getting any errors what so ever. I searched around but didn't find any answers, its an odd one and not sure if I'm searching with the right criteria or not. Here's a link to the page (view source on it to see the code - for now its just simple HTML & Javascript):

http://www.acsout.com/maintenance.html

So when the page loads, 7 of the rows are hidden with this:

```
document.getElementById('frow3').style.display = 'none';
```

For each row, to calculate the line total, I'm using this:

```
function l1calc(){
    if (document.getElementById('up1').value != '' && document.getElementById('q1').value != ''){
        tot1 = document.getElementById('q1').value * document.getElementById('up1').value;
        document.getElementById("lt1").value = parseFloat(Math.round(tot1 * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);
    }
}
```

function l1calc() works fine

The next one, that isn't working, is the same, with different variables:

```
function l2calc(){
    if (document.getElementById('up2').value && document.getElementById('q2').value){
        tot2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('q2').value) *     parseFloat(document.getElementById('up2').value);
        document.getElementById('lt2').value = tot2;
    }
}
```

The link i posted brings you to the page which will let you view source to see the full code and test it to see what i'm referring to.

If I change (in function l2calc) the last line to be:

```
document.getElementById('lt1').value = tot2;
```

then the lt1 field shows the value when the function is triggered. But when it is as it should be for l2calc

```
document.getElementById('lt2').value = tot2;
```

the input field lt2 never shows the value, it just stays blank. The same goes for the rest of the fields in the line total column.

Comment: 404 effort not found.

Comment: you have to post the code here. a wall of text is likely to go unread and the downvotes will rampage.

Comment: I posted a link to the page. I'll post some of the code in addition to the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line is wrong in your script (in `posubtotal`)

```
if(document.getElementById("lt2").value = null){ // <-- == null
  polt2 = 0;
}
```

I used firebug, and saw the hardcoded `568` in `l2calc` with a breakpoint, and then saw the value vanish. So I followed the code.

Comment: Thank you so much ... like the title says, stuipd simple, I should have caught that. Thank you for the help! Firebug is a part of firefox, right? Its odd as chrome didn't show me any errors!

Comment: Chrome Dev tools would have caught it too. Try `F-12` and then set a break point in the [debugger](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/javascript-debugging). This is valid syntax, so you won't get an error. The computer assumes you know what you're doing. Maybe you want to assign `null` in a `if`.

Comment: Thanks again ... I do alot more in PHP than javascript, I just had a blank out on using == instead of =. I'll try that next time - grateful for your fast help!

Comment: ironically, I ended up changing the code:
  `if(document.getElementById("lt2").value){
posubs = parseFloat(posubs) + parseFloat(document.getElementById("lt2").value)
}
if(document.getElementById("lt3").value){
posubs = parseFloat(posubs) + parseFloat(document.getElementById("lt3").value)
}
if(document.getElementById("lt4").value){
posubs = parseFloat(posubs) + parseFloat(document.getElementById("lt4").value)
}`